# Powershell - how to use Close-AzStorageFileHandle

Tags: azure, powershell

When I delete files on an Azure fileshare, they reappear the next day.

This [msftlink](https://learn.microsoft.com/th-th/azure/storage/files/storage-troubleshoot-windows-file-connection-problems#unable-to-delete-a-file-or-directory-in-an-azure-file-share) says I can use the cmdlet "Close-AzStorageFileHandle".  When I run it it says StorageContext not found.  I am new to Powershell.  Can someone give me an example script?  Confused.

> Close-AzStorageFileHandle -ShareName "louis" -Recursive -CloseAll

Answer (score 1):

It appears I have to pipe it?  Is this the correct way?

```
New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName "mystorage" -StorageAccountKey "mykey==" | Close-AzStorageFileHandle -ShareName "myshare" -Recursive -CloseAll
```